# How to suppress whitespace from inputs in tcsh?

Tags: unix, input, alias, tcsh

In tcsh I'm trying to make an alias like

```
alias getit "mv /somedir/$* ."
```

If I then do

```
 getit foo.txt
```

tcsh tries to execute

```
mv /somedir/ foo.txt
```

i.e. it inserts an unwanted whitespace and tries to move /somedir/ into a non-existent directory foo.txt and rightly complains that it does not exit. What's the right way to write this command and suppress the whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias getit "mv /somedir/\!:1 ."
```

This will take the first argument passed to the alias and place it in the location of `\!:1`.  If you want the glob form (all arguments) then you would use `\!*`, although I don't think that's what you want in this situation.